# Swift: Make Numbers start from right to left

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm currently implementing a football table with the stats of each team shown. I used optical formats to setup the view. Seeing in the picture below.
But as you can see the numbers are starting on the left and then expand to the right. What I want is that the small numbers are starting on the right and expand to the left.

Is there a way to do that and is there maybe a better way than using optical formats because as you can see in my code it is very long and messy?

Picture with numbers starting at wrong end:

[image: Wrong picture]

My code:

```
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-8-[v0(30)]-16-[v1(28)]-12-[v2(70)]-15-[v3(15)]-28-[v4(15)]-25-[v5(15)]-10-[v6(15)]-10-[v7(15)]-16-[v8(40)]-8-[v9(20)]", views: tablePlaceLabel, teamLogoLabel, teamNameLabel, gamesPlayedLabel, pointsLabel, winLabel, drawLabel, losLabel, goalsLabel, goalsDiffLabel)
```

extension:

```
extension UIView {
func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()

    for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
        let key = "v\(index)"
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
    }

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}
}
```

Comment: Try setting the justification: `losLabel.textAlignment = .right`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the text alignment using this code:

```
label.textAlignment = .right
```